# Can you replace an inline comment in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex, comments

I´m writing a program to scan code files and have to remove comments first.
Single- and Multiline comments.

The single line comments seem to work out perfectly but somehow the multiline part doesn´t seem to work properly.

It does find the multiline comment but doesn´t replace it.
when using

```
outputCode.replace(multilineComment, '');
```

my function:

```
  // remove all comments by removing everything between the matches indexes and the next endOfCommentRegex
  const removeAllComments = async (endOfCommentRegex: RegExp, matches: RegExpMatchArray[]) => {
    let comments: string[] = [];
    matches.forEach(async match => {
      // find the next endOfCommentRegex after the match.index
      const endOfCommentMatch = outputCode.slice(match.index).match(endOfCommentRegex);
      if (endOfCommentMatch) {
        // store everything between the match.index and the endOfCommentMatch.index in a variable if the char at match.index - 1 is not a : (for https://...)
        if (outputCode.charAt(match.index! - 1) !== ':') {
          comments.push(outputCode.slice(match.index, match.index! + endOfCommentMatch.index! + 2));
        }
      }
    });
    // remove all comments from the outputCode
    comments.forEach(comment => {
      outputCode = outputCode.replace(comment, '');
    });
  };
```

and call the function like so:

```
// check for all multiline comments
const multiMatches = [...outputCode.matchAll(/\/\*/g)];
if (multiMatches.length !== 0) {
  await removeAllComments(/\*\//, multiMatches);
}
```

expected output: the file(string)content without the multiline in it.

current output: file(string)content + multilineComment + file(string)content

I have no idea, why it cocatinates the string that weird instead of simply replacing the comment.

Any idea what could be wrong here?

edit: like I said, it *does* find the multiline comment and safes it in the comments array like so: `"/* multiline dummy comment */"`

Answer (score 1):

This regex works for me `/(\/\*(.*?\n*)*?\*\/)/g`

- **/** - start of regex
- **(** - start of capturing group
- **\ /** - escaped / (matches /)
- **\ *** - escaped * (matches *)
- **(** - start of capturing group
- **.*?** - any character (optional, lazy - matches as few as possible)
- **\n*** - line break (optional)
- **)*?** - end of capturing group (optional, lazy - matches as few as possible)
- **\ *** - escaped * (matches *)
- **\ /** - escaped / (matches /)
- **)** - end of capturing group
- **/** - end of regex
- **g** - global flag

```
let reg = /(\/\*(.*?\n*)*?\*\/)/g;
outputCode = outputCode.replace(reg, '');
```

Comment: Hey thanks! 
I made a little mistake, which I even fixed in my post, so the code I wrote should work like so as well. Since I had to add some more checks to my regex and when to delete code or not. But yours seems to work so far as well!